# Quickly create a list of strings

Tags: string, powershell

Consider the following example.  You have a list of server names copied to the clipboard.

How would you quickly create a PowerShell variable containing the list of strings?

Now I know you just wrap the strings seen below in single quotes, but how could this be done programmatically?

Sample:

```
$list = @(
One
Two
Three
)
```

Comment: Going to +1 the answer by @AnsgarWiechers since that method works across PowerShell versions.  Also a helpful answer, Powershell V5 can do gcb -> Get-Clipboard and there also is a Set-Clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`Clipboard`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx) class from the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms | Out-Null

$clp = [Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetText() -split "`r`n"
```

The clipboard content is returned as a single string, so you need to split it at line breaks to get an array of lines.

Another option would be the `InternetExplorer.Application` COM object:

```
$ie = New-Object -COM 'InternetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Navigate("about:blank")
while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }

$clp = $ie.Document.parentWindow.clipboardData.getData('text') -split "`r`n"

$ie.Quit()
```

However, for this to work you must put `about:blank` in a security zone where you allow programmatic clipboard access for scripts:

[image: Security Settings → Scripting → Allow Programmatic clipboard access]

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.

Comment: I think I have a faster method.  Line 1 in ISE `$list = @'` then as many lines as you want.  Last line is `'@`  Now `$list` contains the list of strings.  For example, `$list.ToUpper()`

Comment: @user4317867 How exactly would creating a multiline string fetch anything from the clipboard? Not to mention that a multiline string still is a single string, not a list of strings.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers my fault, I was rushing.  My aim was to paste multiple lines into the ISE and create a variable with those string.  For example, paste into `1.txt` then `$var = Get-Content 1.txt` followed by `foreach($a in $var){"something on $a"}`

Comment: @user4317867 The code I posted already gives you what `Get-Content` would return without having to take the detour of writing it to a file first. Or did you mean you want a way to paste clipboard text as a variable defining a list of strings into the IDE? That would be an entirely different question than what you asked.

Comment: It looks that way, I was being lazy.  Currently I'm using `$files = @(` each line following that is `'file1'` and `'file2'` and so on.  This allows me to add new files into `$files` which is piped to `Remove-Item` easily.  This question is supposed to be asking "Is there any easier way to wrap lines in the ISE in quotes?"

Comment: Like I said: that's an entirely different question. Either edit your current question to say what you actually meant, or (better) post it as a new question that says what you actually meant.

Comment: Let's cap this off, the `$var= [Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetText() -split "`r`n"` is the best overall answer.  This sort of thing should be built into PowerShell.  -Thanks @AnsgarWiechers